# Determine the number of all rooted forests with a set of vertices $[n]$, where $n \geq 1$ (Cayley's formula?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

A rooted tree is an ordered pair ($T, v_T$), where $T$ is a tree and $v_T$ is a distinguished vertex of tree $T$. A rooted tree forest is a set consisting of one or more rooted trees with pairwise disjoint sets of vertices. The set of vertices of a rooted forest is the sum of the sets of vertices of all its trees. Determine the number of all rooted forests with a set of vertices $[n]$, where $n \geq 1$.

Now, the answer seems to be $(n+1)^{n-1}$ simply given by [Cayleys formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula). However, I wanted somebody to verify that I understand the problem correctly and tell me if that's the correct answer.

Comment: For any rooted forest of $n$ vertices, add a vertex $\infty$ and make all the roots its children. You get a tree of $n+1$ nodes. For any tree of $n+1$ nodes, one of them labelled at $\infty$, remove that vertex and its edges, and you get a rooted forest, where the roots are the vertices that were children of $\infty$.

Comment: @NDB ok, but what does it have to do with the original problem? I don't think I understand that hint.

Comment: It stablished a bijection between what Cayley's theorem counts with $(n+1)^{n-1}$ (the number of trees with $n+1$ labelled vertices) and what you want to count (rooted forests on $n$ vertices).

Comment: Ohh, now I think I get it. Tank you! @NDB